# Hibernate Duplicate Row creation

Tags: hibernate, join, mapping, one-to-many, duplicates

I have the classes as below:

**Student -**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String fName;
private String lName;
private String mName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Set<Phone> phones;
```

**Phone -**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int phoneId;


    private int phoneNumber;
```

So, my Phone table will have a foreign key referencing to Student table. Now if I do a create, it works fine with each row in the Student and Phone tables.

But if I do an update like say add a mname later on for the student, it creates another row in the phone table with the same data as the first row but now the second row will have reference to the phone table and first row foreign key is null.

I want to keep the above schema as is. I want the row to be created in the Phone table only when there is really a change. How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: You are setting the id of the Student as JoinColumn, try to set the phoneId and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

It's just working fine, and your `@OneToMany` relationship is correct. Just be sure to use the `Session.update(Object)` method when you update your student.

If you use `Session.save(Object)` while updating, then it will create a new row with a new `id` for the student (the case you are experiencing).

If you don't want to guess whether you have to insert or update, you can use `Session.saveOrUpdate(Object)` method and let Hibernate decide if student has to be inserted or updated: it works fine. Just be sure that your student has the correct `id` set, as Hibernate will use it to update the row.